# Limit selected checkboxes with Bootstrap button.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, limit

I'm trying to set maximal enabled/clickable buttons(checkboxes with Bootstrap button.js) to 3.

How to limit ordinary checkboxes, no problem. But what about this nice feature on Bootstrap? Is there a way to do it?

Here is example: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio